# jquery slide and bounce content by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, easing, bounce

I don't know why this works. I am using the jquery library 2.1.1 for it and checked different versions. The goto is fired by an

```
    function goto(id, t){
            //animate to the div id.
            $(".inner_slide")
                .animate(
                    {"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 
                    400
                );

            // add active class to the current link
            $(t).addClass('active');
        }
```

but not this part (replacing):

```
                .animate(
                    {"left": -($(id).position().left)}, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                });
```

What is the problem with the arguments `duration` and `easing`?

Comment: You're asking why it works ?

Comment: FYI, you probably have to include jQuery UI for the animation effects library.

Comment: it did the job thanks =)